# PHPUnit how to display progress as it goes?

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm running my tests from CLI but I have to always wait till all of them are done before I can see the progress.

```
........................................SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS  63 / 285 ( 22%)
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS 126 / 285 ( 44%)
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS 189 / 285 ( 66%)
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS 252 / 285 ( 88%)
S................................
```

I could not find anywhere how to make it display '.', 'S', 'F' as it goes.

Comment: Looks like you have output buffering enabled at some point

Answer (score -1):

After looking into the code of PHPUnit I have found this line that was causing my problems:

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.7/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php#L203

I changed NULL to 'php://stdout'. Now it works as expected :)

Comment: No line in PHPUnit is causing your problems, it is either your code or your PHP configuration.